# Can't return a promise chain with a catch block on the end

Tags: swift, promisekit

This used to work but with version 6 of PromiseKit this...

```
func checkIn(request: CheckinRequest) -> Promise<CheckinResponse> {
    let p = checkinService.checkIn(request: request)
        .then { r -> Promise<CheckinResponse> in
            return .value(r)
        }.catch { e in

        }
    return p
}
```

... gives ...

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'PMKFinalizer' to return type
> 'Promise'

How can I add a catch block and continue to return the chain to the calling function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to remove the `catch` block as below,

```
func checkIn(request: CheckinRequest) -> Promise<CheckinResponse> {
     let p = checkinService.checkIn(request: request)
          .then { r -> Promise<CheckinResponse> in
              return .value(r)
        }
      return p
}
```

Using the catching block here is irrelevant as the `error` should be handled by the callee.

---

`Guarantee` class is a wrapper `class` to make discardable `result` calls. So we can create a method that will process the `promise` so that we will just use the `.done` callback to use that `result` as below,

```
extension Promise {

    func result() -> Guarantee<T> {
        return Guarantee<T>(resolver: { [weak self] (body) in
            self?.done({ (result) in
                body(result)
            }).catch({ (error) in
                print(error)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Now you can simply do,

```
let request = CheckinRequest()
checkinService.checkIn(request: request).result().done { response in
    // Check in response
}
```

You can still use chaining for multiple promises as below,

```
checkinService.checkIn(request: request).result().then { (result) -> Promise<Bool> in
        // Use reuslt
        return .value(true)
    }.done { bool in
        print(bool)
    }.catch { (e) in
        print(e)
}
```

Comment: But then I have to repeat the catch block for every callee.

Comment: Yes, that’s how you can handle a promise. My guess is you want a method where you can tell the result type and get that result only. So for that you need to create a generic method with completion block and no return type of Promise. Anti-promise but this is what we needed. Call this completion in the .done callback of Promise and handle the error in catch block. Second option is to extend Promise by introducing a method that has discardableResult on the result to mute the catching block warning on every call.

Comment: @IanWarburton I updated the answer with one helper method. This could be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you need to know is described [here](https://mxcl.dev/PromiseKit/news/2018/02/PromiseKit-6.0-Released/), just scroll to the `.catch{ /*…*/ }.finally` section.

You can use this solution if you want to keep the same functionality:

```
func checkIn(request: CheckinRequest) -> Promise<CheckinResponse> {
    let p = checkinService.checkIn(request: request).then { r -> Promise<CheckinResponse> in
        return .value(r)
    }
    p.catch { e in

    }
    return p
}
```

However, it is not recommended to use this pattern. `catch` is a chain  terminator. Therefore, you should refactor your code. Check [Kamran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53770818/2229783) for inspiration.

Comment: FYI, "here" is a Bad link